# How to remove indirect left-recursion from grammar

Tags: parsing, recursion, antlr, grammar, left-recursion

I have some mutually left-recursive ANTLR code:

```
expr: int_liter
| bool_liter
| char_liter
| str_liter
| pair_liter
| ident
| array_elem
| unary_oper expr
| expr binary_oper expr
| OPEN_PARENTHESES expr CLOSE_PARENTHESES
;

array_elem:  expr  OPEN_BRACKET expr CLOSE_BRACKET ;
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR 4 can handle direct left-recursion only, but your grammar contains indirect left recursion from the rules `expr` → `array_elem` → `expr`. The easiest way to resolve this problem in your particular grammar is to inline the `array_elem` rule into the `expr` rule, and use labeled outer alternatives to assign meaningful names to each of the alternatives in `expr`.

```
expr
  : int_liter                                # someLabel
  | bool_liter                               # someLabel               
  | char_liter                               # someLabel
  | str_liter                                # someLabel
  | pair_liter                               # someLabel
  | ident                                    # someLabel
  | expr OPEN_BRACKET expr CLOSE_BRACKET     # array_elem
  | unary_oper expr                          # someLabel
  | expr binary_oper expr                    # someLabel
  | OPEN_PARENTHESES expr CLOSE_PARENTHESES  # someLabel
  ;
```

Note the following constraints around using labeled outer alternatives:

1. No two outer alternatives can share a label, and labels cannot match any rule name; labels must be unique throughout the grammar.
2. If one outer alternative of a rule is labeled (e.g. the `array_elem` alternative), then *all* outer alternatives for that rule must be labeled.

Comment: I am shocked to learn that a modern tool like ANTLR cannot do what yacc can since the 70's.

Comment: @Ingo: ANTLR is an LL parser generator; YACC is an LALR parser generator. You're comparing apples to rice.

Comment: This is news to me. I always thought that the *LR* in *ANTLR* promises LALR. Anyway, I am happy I never took the effort to learn ANTLR and sticked with yacc (or, pbyacc -j, if you need something java-ish)

Comment: @280Z28 hey thanks for the answer! Another question, I tried to do the labelling and now the array_elem rule is said undefined when called from other rules like this

`assign_lhs: ident
          | array_elem
          | pair_elem 
          ;
`